# Showing message while adding configurable product to cart (magento)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

While adding configurable product from product list page to cart showing a warning like "Please specify the product's option(s)." in magento version 1.7.0.2.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is because configurable product are association of simple product, customer have to choose one option from dropdown of simple product, and this is required field, so if you add to cart from product list then it will give you this error. Because you have to choose one option.